# Java Socket Programming : Connection Refused

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, lan

I've been recently working on developing a messenger that works on LAN. I've written the java code for both server and client.

Server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class Server
{   
    private ServerSocket ss;
    private Hashtable outputStreams = new Hashtable();

    public Server( int port ) throws IOException 
    {
        listen( port );
    }

    private void listen( int port ) throws IOException 
    {
        ss = new ServerSocket( port );
        System.out.println( "Listening on "+ss );

    // Keep accepting connections forever
    while (true) 
    {
        // Grab the next incoming connection
        Socket s = ss.accept();

        // Tell the world we've got it
        System.out.println( "Connection from "+s );

        // Create a DataOutputStream for writing data to the other side
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream( s.getOutputStream() );

        // Save this stream so we don't need to make it again
        outputStreams.put( s, dout );

        // Create a new thread for this connection, and then forget about it
        new ServerThread( this, s );
    }
}

// Get an enumeration of all the OutputStreams, one for each client connected to us
Enumeration getOutputStreams() 
{
    return outputStreams.elements();
}

// Send a message to all clients (utility routine)
void sendToAll( String message ) 
{
    // We synchronize on this because another thread might be calling removeConnection() and this would screw us up as we tried to walk through the list
    synchronized( outputStreams ) 
    {
        // For each client ...
        for (Enumeration e = getOutputStreams(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) 
        {
            // ... get the output stream ...
            DataOutputStream dout = (DataOutputStream)e.nextElement();
            // ... and send the message

            try {
                dout.writeUTF( message );
            } catch( IOException ie ) { System.out.println( ie ); }
        }
    }
}

// Remove a socket, and it's corresponding output stream, from our
// list. This is usually called by a connection thread that has
// discovered that the connectin to the client is dead.
void removeConnection( Socket s ) 
{
    // Synchronize so we don't mess up sendToAll() while it walks
    // down the list of all output streamsa
    synchronized( outputStreams ) 
    {
        // Tell the world
        System.out.println( "Removing connection to "+s );

        // Remove it from our hashtable/list
        outputStreams.remove( s );

        // Make sure it's closed
        try {
            s.close();
        } catch( IOException ie ) {
            System.out.println( "Error closing "+s );
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// Main routine
static public void main( String args[] ) throws Exception 
{
    // Create a Server object, which will automatically begin accepting connections.
    new Server( 5252 );
}
}
```

Client.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
// Components for the visual display of the chat windows
private TextField tf = new TextField();
private TextArea ta = new TextArea();

// The socket connecting us to the server
private Socket socket;

// The streams we communicate to the server; these come from the socket
private DataOutputStream dout;
private DataInputStream din;

// Constructor
public Client(String host, int port)
{
    // Set up the screen
    ta.setEditable(false);
    setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    add( "North", tf );
    add( "Center", ta );

    setSize(200,200);
    setVisible(true);
    // We want to receive messages when someone types a line
    // and hits return, using an anonymous class as
    // a callback
    tf.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            tf.setText(" ");
            processMessage( e.getActionCommand() );
        }
    } );

    // Connect to the server
    try {
        // Initiate the connection
        socket = new Socket( host, port );

        // We got a connection! Tell the world
        System.out.println( "connected to "+socket );

        din = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );
        dout = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );

        // Start a background thread for receiving messages
        new Thread( this ).start();
    } catch( IOException ie ) { System.out.println( ie ); }
}

// Gets called when the user types something
private void processMessage( String message ) 
{
    try {
        // Send it to the server
        dout.writeUTF( message );

        // Clear out text input field
        tf.setText( "" );
    } catch( IOException ie ) { System.out.println( ie ); }
}

// Background thread runs this: show messages from other window
public void run() 
{
    try 
    {
        // Receive messages one-by-one, forever
        while (true) 
        {
            // Get the next message
            String message = din.readUTF();

            // Print it to our text window
            ta.append( message+"\n" );
        }
    } catch( IOException ie ) { System.out.println( ie ); }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Client("192.168.29.12",5252);
}
}
```

These are the two files, and I've cross checked every possible resource on internet for the validity of this code and it is right. Point of concern is the code is running fine on localhost that is when my system is both server and client (when the host address is 127.0.0.1) but when I run server on my system and client on some other system connected to the same LAN as mine (ie the host) client window says connection refused even when The SERVER is RUNNING and I've removed ALL FIREWALL SETTING.
I'll really thankful to the one who could help. I am really not able to deal with this. I've tried every possible solution.

By the way, for internet we use proxy server. does that have anything to do with the lan connection?

Comment: Can you ping the other computers?

Comment: OK, just to be sure, you get 'Connection refused' almost immediately, not 'Unreachable' after a long delay?

Comment: Also, the Server ctor never returns.  That's just weird...

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but try to make a test by scanning ports on this computer, nmap is a good tool. At least you will know if ports are locked.

Comment: Try `telnet 192.168.29.12 5252` from command line. What do you get?

Comment: Yeah, what @Dima says.  It's called debugging.

Comment: @joey.enfield yes i did ping the ip to ensure that connection is working and ping was successful means it was showing reply from that ip.

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, I get Connection refused immediately..without any delay. And I've already tried putting the constructor code in another function and calling that function with an object but that didn't work either.

Comment: If your on a corporate network (you mention that there is a proxy server) it could be possible that they are blocking all higher ports.

Comment: @Dima its saying telnet isn't a recognized command. Can that be the issue? I'm sorry if I sound stupid but how does that really matter? means telnet is different, isn't it?

Comment: @joey.enfield i'm using my university's network. And now how can I know if they've blocked the ports?

Comment: @Nidhijain what OS are you using?

Comment: @Nidhijain [telnet for wnidows7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @Dima hey, its successful! now the telnet command works. It says, Connecting To 192.168.29.12...Could not open connection to the host, on port 525
2: Connect failed

Comment: @Nidhijain how about when you run it on the same machine, where your server is running? Try `telnet 192.168.29.12 5252` and then `telnet 127.0.0.1 5252`, does either one work? Also, the error you pasted below has an extra space between "525" and "2". Are you sure you typed the command right?

Comment: @Dima hey that space is nothing, "2" was in different line in cmd line that's why. and on the machine at which server is running telnet 127.0.0.1 works but the other one doesn't.

Comment: @Nidhijain If "space is nothing", the the port number is wrong :) It is supposed to be "5252", and you have it as "525".  On the machine, where the server is running, do `ipconfig` in command line. What does it say?

Comment: @Dima ipconfig works fine..ip address 192.168.29.12..but telnet not working with this ip